# CSS dropdown menu without the right layout

Tags: html, css, dropdown

this is my first post. Hope I'm specific enough to get some help :)

I created a dropdown menu in my navigation bar for my clanwebsite. But I can't change the css in a way that it would be the same as my other titles from the navigation bar.

Also when I go over it with my cursor, the login button is being moved. And the css of my navigation is different when I go to the Main team page in the dropdown menu.

Thanks!

NOTE don't mind the php. Still working on that.

my HTML of the home page

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Opmaak.css">
<title>WKG</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Line-up.html">Line-ups</a></li>
    <li><div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Teams</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="Mainteam.html">Main Team</a>
        <a href="Team2.html">Team 2</a>
        </div>
<li><a href="Matchen.html">Matchen</a></li>
<li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="Games.html">Games</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html
```

my CSS

```
p {
font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: visible;
background-color: #444;
}

li {
float: left;
box-shadow: 15px 15px 50px #888888;
font-size: 20px;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: darkgray;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 50px;
text-decoration: inherit;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px crimson;
border-color: crimson;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content a {
display: block;
background-color: slategray;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: inherit;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.dropbtn {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: slategray;
color: darkgray;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 50px;
text-decoration: inherit;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px crimson;
border-color: crimson;
font-size: 20px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

. dropbtn:hover {
background-color: crimson;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
background-color: crimson;
padding: 20px 50px;
}
```

and my Main Team page

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Opmaak.css">
<title>WKG</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Line-up.html">Line-ups</a></li>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Teams</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="Mainteam.html">Main Team</a>
        <a href="Team2.html">Team 2</a>
        </div>
<li><a href="Matchen.html">Matchen</a></li>
<li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="Games.html">Games</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Welcome! Please remove the unnecessary code from your question. If you are asking about dropdown, create a snippet with the dropdown only (and css too of course). It's hard to read a lot of irrelevant code. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I deleted all of the irrelevant code.

Comment: Can't you insert UL/LI element and within it the button and DIV elements? Basically, create the correct structure with the JS/jQuery.

Comment: `But I can't change the css in a way that it would be the same as my other titles from the navigation bar` - As much as I can see ithe dropdown items looks the same. Isn't? I created jsbin for you. http://output.jsbin.com/goniyisoqa